# Django python AttributeError Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'shop'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

i am writing module of Django shopping site user can add shop and products

when user fill the form for adding product and hit submit it django give this error,
it would be very helpful if someone can put some light on the problem, thank you.

**Error**

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'shop'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/15/add_product/
Django Version:     2.1.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'shop'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\MILAN\PycharmProjects\DjangoProject\shopsurfer\views.py in form_valid, line 191
Python Executable:  C:\Users\MILAN\PycharmProjects\DjangoProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.0
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\MILAN\\PycharmProjects\\DjangoProject',
 'C:\\Users\\MILAN\\PycharmProjects\\DjangoProject\\venv\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\MILAN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\MILAN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\MILAN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\MILAN\\PycharmProjects\\DjangoProject\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\MILAN\\PycharmProjects\\DjangoProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\MILAN\\PycharmProjects\\DjangoProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg']

Server time:    Tue, 12 Feb 2019 14:37:12 +0000
```

**product_form.html**

this is where all the html code which is generating the form form the input

```
{% extends 'shopsurfer/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Add a New Product{% endblock %}
{% block album_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container=fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}


{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="song_title">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class ="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Models.py** file contain Shop, Product, User model which is stored in sqlite default database

```
class Product(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    lot = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=0)
    specs = models.CharField(max_length=5120)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=16)
    product_logo = models.FileField(default='')


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shopsurfer:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Forms.py** this is form field which is used to create form for the model

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'lot', 'specs', 'price', 'product_logo']
```

**Views.py** here is the code for the AddProduct which is i thing contain error but i am not able to find what.

```
class AddProduct (LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login_user'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    model = Product
    fields = ['name', 'category', 'lot', 'specs', 'price', 'product_logo']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object_product = form.save(commit=False)
        object_product.shop = self.request.shop
        object_product.save()
        return super(AddProduct, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Can you please add some more detail about why you do `object_product.shop = self.request.shop`? That is where your error comes from. The reason is that the `request` object does not have a `shop` member variable. It will only exist if you put it there directly, or if you have a Middleware that does it for you.

Comment: i want to associate a product with shop that is the why i have wrote that line. i want to add shop as a foreign key in product.

Comment: I understand that. But where does that `shop` value come from? Is it on the form? Or from the URL? Or from a custom Middleware?

Comment: now i also under stand the problem , but and want to add shop value in the view.py code but where to get it?

Comment: Show the URL configuration for this view, maybe we can get it from there.

Comment: url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/add_product/$', views.AddProduct.as_view(), name='add_product'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `kwargs` we can get vaule of the primary key and we can use that value to get the object `Shop`

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/add_product/$', views.AddProduct.as_view(), name='add_product'),
```

**views.py**

```
pk = self.kwargs['pk']
object.shop = get_object_or_404(Shop, pk=pk)
```

and by doing this we can able to store the value to the database.

by the way thanks for helping @malberts